# Generating Random two-dimensional points in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am newbie in Matlab , and I am trying to generate two-dimensional random numbers based on Gaussian (normal) distribution and uniform distribution. assume that I want to create a 2 different dataset (Gaussian(1800 pairs) and Uniform(1200 pairs)) which is going to use for Data mining tasks/algorithms (over-fitting in two-dimensional data) example.

other important issue is that the data points should be in range of 0-20.

I've tried this for Gaussian distribution

```
SIGMA = [.5 .05; .05 .5 ];
temp = mvnrnd([-3 0], SIGMA,1800);
```

these codes generates numbers between -5 to 5 and I want to generate 0-20 so I've tried

```
SIGMA = [0 20];
```

but I get the range -20 to 20

How can I get the range of 0-20 ?

Comment: what have you tired so far? have you looked into `rand` and `randn`? show us some code...

Comment: Gaussian random variables don't have hard bounds.  Extreme values are just unlikely.  The best you can do is offset the mean, which is controlled by the first argument to mvnrnd.  Try [10 10].

Comment: `mvnrnd` is not a normal distribution (unless you maybe choose the right parameters to fit a special case). Use `randn` instead.

Comment: @DanielR?? `help mvnrnd: Random vectors from the multivariate normal distribution.`

Comment: @Peter: each dimension independent normal distributed is a special case of the multivariate normal distribution. To reduce it to the simple case, you have to choose the correct parameters, which I currently don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Gaussian_r=10+(10/3)*randn(1800,1)
```

Here i used the 3 sigma rule where 99.7% of the random variables will fall between mean - sigma to mean + 3 sigma which means that there is still 0.3% that might fall outside the area you specified if that's not good enough for you you can make sigma smaller

```
Uniform_r = 20*rand(1200,1)
```

if you want these to be integers use randi instead

check [randn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) [randi](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) [rand](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html)

Answer (score 1):

Uniform:
r = randi(20,2,1200)

Gaussian:
The function randn is a Gaussian distribution with standard deviation (sigma) = 1 and mean (mu) = 0. A real normal distribution is not constrained to an interval there is just decreasing probabilities of events as you get further from the mean. As your sample size gets larger the probability of getting an extreme value increases. Assuming you want your distribution centered (mean) around 10 you can pick a suitably small sigma to make an outlier in 1800 samples very unlikely, then make extra sure it does not happen with a conditional.

If you are within 6sigma with 3600 samples the probability of a sample being outside is very small (7.1e-4% you can see this in MATLAB with 1-erf(6/sqrt(2))^3600). So one reasonable sigma might be 10/6 (1.6667). This gives us:

r = 10 + 1.6667*randn(2,1800)
%just in case
r(r>20) = 20;
r(r<0) = 0;

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution